# Bluetooth doesn't turn on AOSP 6.0 + Nexus 5X

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am not able to get Bluetooth to turn on with AOSP built from source (for  both MMB29V and MTC19T)

I downloaded both versions of AOSP (android-6.0.1_r17 and android-6.0.1_r25 respectively), I built both and tried to load  system, userdata and cache built from aosp on Nexus 5X device.

I also load the vendor image from corresponding factory binaries.

Device boots, other functions work (camera, wifi etc. Not exhaustively tested) but Bluetooth doesn't turn on.

On switching on BT, lot of logs are printed, I think these lines might have some significance:

```
01-04 03:22:33.043 2441-2462/? E/bt_vendor: connect_to_local_socket: ACCEPT 
01-04 03:22:33.045 2441-2462/? E/bt_vendor: failed to connect (Connection refused)
01-04 03:22:33.046 2441-2462/? E/bt_hci_h4: hal_open opened the wrong number of ports: got -1, expected 1.
```

What can I do to get Bluetooth to work on this device?

I can get more parts of logs if required.

Comment: Do you have permission?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. I am not turning bluetooth on from my app. I am trying this from Settings->Bluetooth. No modifications are done to AOSP code.

Answer (score 0):

GPS,

From your debug output, it looks like the HAL module is not communicating well with the driver. This could point to an issue in either location. Unfortunately, if the driver is proprietary, then there is little you can do to fix this problem. If not, make sure the HAL module calls line up with the driver, and rebuild.

P.S. Hal modules and drivers are usually in your device directory.